# Class 'Asana' not found in Laravel Asana

Tags: php, mysql, rest, laravel-4, asana

I am developing a timetracker web application and I want to sync my Asana tasks (https://app.asana.com/ ) into webpage. I am Using laravel restful service for this. I've successfully installed the Laravel-Asana package ( https://github.com/Torann/laravel-asana). But Now getting error with getProjects() method.

I configured the Asana API Key & Asana default workspace in `\vendor\torann\laravel-asana\src\config\config.php`

Error is **Class 'Asana' not found**

Code : .

```
protected static $restful = true;

   public function task()
   {
     Asana::getProjects();
     echo "task Fetched";
   }
}
?>
```

Anyone please help me. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are missing some important points in package documentation.

If you are using the class `Asana` it should be loaded in to the project.

So go to your app file `app/config/app.php` and add one new item in the providers array by adding comma at the end:

```
'Torann\LaravelAsana\ServiceProvider'
```